# Apply function on raster

Tags: raster, r

I often need to apply functions on every raster cell. Unfortunately I don't know how to use a efficient method like *calc*, so I am using very slow for-loops.

For example:

```r
logistic_function <- function(x, x_null, L = 1, k = 0.5) {
  y = 1 / (L + exp(1)^(-k*(x - x_null)))
  return(y)
}

#random input raster
r <- raster(ncol = 370, nrow = 202)
values(r) <- runif(ncell(r))

#output raster
r_log <- raster(ncol = 370, nrow = 202)

#inefficient for-loop
for (this_col in 1:ncol(r)) {
  for (this_row in 1:nrow(r)) {

      r_log[this_row, this_col] <- logistic_function(x=r[this_row, this_col],
                                                 x_null = cellStats(r, median),
                                                 k=0.5)
  }
}
```

I would like to do something like this:

```r
r_log <- calc(r, cellStats(r, median), fun=logistic_function)
```

Comment: The global median of the raster is a static parameter. Just set it as a global variable that is called in the logistic function. Then you can use calc, eg `x_null = cellStats(r, 'median')` Using a for loop here is a very bad choice.

Comment: Thank you very much. This works perfect!