# How to apply a function on two rasters in Python?

Tags: python, raster-calculator, rasterio, rioxarray, xarray

I would like to cell-wise function operation on two rasters. While I saw some examples of adding or subtracting two rasters, I'm yet to come across a complex example of how to manipulate rasters using custom functions.

My limited attempt:

```
import rioxarray as rxr

# Read rasters
A_raster = rxr.open_rasterio(A_raster_path, masked=True).squeeze()
B_raster = rxr.open_rasterio(B_raster_path, masked=True).squeeze()

# Making sure that raster dimensions match
B_raster = B_raster.rio.reproject_match(A_raster)
B_raster = B_raster.assign_coords({"x": A_raster.x, "y": A_raster.y})

# a placeholder 
C_raster = np.zeros(A_raster.shape, dtype=A_raster.dtype)

def test_fn(a,b):
    if np.isnan(a) or np.isnan(b):
        return 0
    elif a*b <10:
        return a*b**1.75
    elif a*b < 20:
        return b**2 + a
    else:
        return a**3 + b**3

C_raster = xarray.apply_ufunc(test_fn, A_raster, B_raster)
```

I'm not sure how to proceed. I believe I'm applying `apply_ufunc` wrong as I receive value error (`(<class 'ValueError'>, ValueError('The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()'), <traceback object at 0x14d0209c0>)`).

Could you provide me guidance on how to proceed further?

Desired output: A new raster similar to the input raster (i.e., A raster) but with updated values.

Relevant Questions:
[Apply function on raster](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/349316/apply-function-on-raster)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that xarray.where would be the tool you want in this scenario:

https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.where.html

It is able to set values based on a condition. You will likely need to call it for each of your conditions in your function separately.